# Dart Scoring Game Using C# Visual Studio 2010 - Alternating player score after evey 3rd score

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, function, loops, methods

Just bought a dartboard and thought to create a little scoring application, so far i have set up the player names and individual buttons to start the game. three games - 301, 501 and 1001, these are the targets scores to get to zero by throwing three darts each in turn by two players.
I have included many buttons for the score of each dart from 20 down to 1, each for single, double, triple, bull, outer bull and a no score button. Once the games starts the first three button presses should be attributed to player one then the following three buttons pressed to allocate the corresponding score to player 2. The games ends with the winning player achieving the target score (or whittles it down to zero).

I could have a player selection button to do this but was after some tips on a way of coding the alternate pattern of scoring to be automatic.

Any help greatly appreciated. Thank you

```
namespace dbstats
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        btnPlay.Visible = false;
        btnReset.Visible = false;
        btnUndo.Visible = false;
        gbDartBoard.Visible = false;
        gbScoreBoard.Visible = false;
        lbP1Select.Visible = false;;
        lbP2Select.Visible = false;
        cmbP1.Visible = false;
        cmbP2.Visible = false;

        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"playerStats.csv");
        foreach (var line in lines)            
        {
            string[] names = line.Split(',');
            if (names[0] != "NAME")
            {
                cmbP1.Items.Add(names[0]);
                cmbP2.Items.Add(names[0]);
            } 
        }
    }

    private void tsm301_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbP1Select.Visible = true;
        cmbP1.Visible = true;
        lbP2Select.Visible = true;
        cmbP2.Visible = true;
        btnPlay.Visible = true;
        tbPlayer1.Text = "301";
        tbPlayer2.Text = "301";

        gamesToolStripMenuItem.Visible = false;
        manageToolStripMenuItem.Visible = false;
    }

    private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cmbP1.SelectedItem == cmbP2.SelectedItem || cmbP1.SelectedItem == null || cmbP2.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Make Sure:" + "\n\n"
                            + "The Players are NOT the same." + "\n"
                            + "&" + "\n"
                            + "At least one selection is NOT left blank", "Choose Again!");
        }
        else
        {
            lbP1Select.Visible = false;
            cmbP1.Visible = false;
            lbP2Select.Visible = false;
            cmbP2.Visible = false;
            btnPlay.Visible = false;

            lbPlayer1.Text = cmbP1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            lbPlayer2.Text = cmbP2.SelectedItem.ToString();

            btnReset.Visible = true;
            btnUndo.Visible = true;
            gbDartBoard.Visible = true;
            gbScoreBoard.Visible = true;
            lbPlayer1.Visible = true; ;
            lbPlayer2.Visible = true;                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is really too vague to answer. What sort of app are you even looking at? Web app? Desktop? I'd suggest looking at a good MVC or MVVM framework.

Comment: wall of text and no code. I'm too lazy to read all that. Post your code and specify your problem with it.

Comment: You say that you have "included many buttons"... so does this imply you have already done some stuff? Is it `ASP.NET`, `WPF`, `WinForms`, or something else?

Comment: @Matt - I'm basically creating a darts scoring calculator which shows a number in a textbox, that number is then subtracted by pressing the corresponding score button.

Comment: @Andrew - I am using winForms created in VS2010 using C#. I am also using a total of 63 buttons which correspond to a score achieved by throwing one dart on a dartboard and wanted to alternate the score for each textbox for two players alternating every three throws. hope this makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a `turnsEntered` member variable to whatever class is managing turns/scoring.

```
// Call after every time a new score is entered. Start at 0.
turnsEntered++;
if (turnsEntered % 3 == 0)
{
    SwitchPlayer(); // However you keep track of current player - switch here
}
```

After the 3rd score is entered it will switch players...after 3 more it will switch again, etc...

You can later check `turnsEntered` to determine when the game is over. Set it back to zero when you reinitialize for a new game.

Comment: Thanks, i've also used radio buttons at the side of each player indicating a turn using your method. getting there now.